# Cannot find module 'styled-components/macro'

Tags: css, reactjs

I tried to create a ReactJS app using a tutorial that involved the following package:

```
import styled, {css} from 'styled-components/macro';
```

However, macro showed me this error:

```
Cannot find module 'styled-components/macro' from '/home/..
```

After searching for this error, I discovered that 'macro' is no longer functional since React version 5.2.1. After removing 'macro', the 'styled-components' are working fine, but the CSS isn't taking any effect.

Is there any module that I can use in place of 'macro'? I don't want to downgrade my React project."

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can still use styled-components without the macro package. The macro package was used to enhance styled-components with additional features like better debugging and minification of CSS. However, since it's no longer functional, you can use styled-components directly.

```
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  background-color: pink;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <StyledButton>Click me</StyledButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Styled-components should work without any issues once you remove the macro package and import styled-components directly. If you're experiencing CSS not taking effect, make sure your styled components are properly defined and rendered in your React components.

> Doc link for better understanding-
> https://dev.to/elijahtrillionz/complete-guide-on-how-to-use-styled-components-in-react-360c